# Switch SQL Server 2012 from Cal Licensing to Core Licensing

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to switch a SQL Server 2012 install from being CAL licensed to Core Licensed with out a complete re-install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, run the installer from the core licensed media, and choose edition upgade.   It will upgrade to core licensed very quickly (basically registry change, not a full reinstall)

Comment: Thanks StrayCatDBA! we're getting ready to try it now, thanks for the info, will reply if it works shortly.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately I leaned this one from experience.